# Accelerometer in a iOS Safari/WebApp in iPhone and iPad

Tags: web-applications, iphone

I have found a way of finding out the orientation of the device (portrait, landscape left, landscape right, upside down) via the listener

```
 <body onorientationchange="updateOrientation();">
```

and in the header

```
function updateOrientation() {

        switch(window.orientation) {
                case 0:
                    // normal
                    // do some cool things...
                    break;

                case -90:
                    // right
                    // do some cool things...
                    break;

                case 90:
                    // left
                    // do some cool things...
                    break;

                case 180:
                    // upside down
                    // do some cool things...
                    break;
        }
}
```

but is it actually possible to find out the X/Y/Z values of the accelerometer in general?

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 4.2, you can use the [DeviceMotionEvent](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/SafariDOMAdditions/Reference/DeviceMotionEventClassRef/DeviceMotionEvent/DeviceMotionEvent.html) class. Here's a blog post describing how to use it:

http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios-accelerometer-websockets-html5